# Kubernetes KUBECONFIG files

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

We have a helm chart and we want to install the chart on cluster in any of the 3 clouds (AWS,Azure and GCP). How can we download the kubeconfig file for a Kubernetes cluster and use it to install the helm chart?

Answer (score 1):

For Azure :

Retrieve a `data` of your cluster :

```hcl
data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "main" {
  name                = "your-cluster"
  resource_group_name = "your-rg"
}
```

In your providers.tf file add the following :

```hcl
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.6"
    }
    helm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/helm"
      version = "2.9.0"
    }
  }
```

If it's ok to use admin kubeconfig :

```hcl
provider "helm" {
  load_config_file       = "false"
  host                   = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_admin_config.0.host
  username               = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_admin_config.0.username
  password               = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_admin_config.0.password
  client_certificate     = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_admin_config.0.client_certificate)}"
  client_key             = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_admin_config.0.client_key)}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_admin_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
}
```

If you want to avoid using the admin kubeconfig :

```hcl
provider "helm" {
  host                   = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config.0.host
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
    command = "./kubelogin"
    args = [
      "get-token",
      "--login",
      "spn",
      "--environment",
      "AzurePublicCloud",
      "--tenant-id",
      var.tenant_id,
      "--server-id",
      var.aad_server_id,
      "--client-id",
      var.client_id,
      "--client-secret",
      var.client_secret
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that you'll need to include the [kubelogin](https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin) binary in the repo. [More details here](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/aad-integrated-kubernetes-cluster-no-longer-able-to-use-kubernetes-provider-following-disabling-local-admin-account/33439).

Then you can install helm chart like this :

```hcl
resource "helm_release" "your-release" {  
  name       = "your-release"
  namespace  = "your-namespace"
  repository = "whatever/repo"
  chart      = "a-chart"
  version    = "1.2.3"
}
```

I'm not sure about GCP or AWS but I wouldn't be surprised the process being similar